# Fabric ignores @hosts decoration

Tags: python, deployment, fabric

I've written a deployment script and I'm using `@hosts` decorators to tell a function which host to use:

```
@hosts('rdp_p11@localhost')
def put_p11(f, path):
    put(f, path)

@hosts('rdp_p12@localhost')
def put_p12(f, path):
    put(f, path)
```

For some reason, I'm getting the following message: 
`No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection:`

I'm running these functions from another function in the `fabfile.py`

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Fabric's documentation [Library Use](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/library.html) states:

> run, sudo and the other operations only look in one place when connecting: env.host_string. All of the other mechanisms for setting hosts are interpreted by the fab tool when it runs, and don’t matter when running as a library.

Since you're calling the functions manually in python, `fab` doesn't process the settings in those, even if you're using it to launch the main function.

You can use a context manager to manipulate `env` easily:

```
from fabric.api import settings
with settings(host_string="myhost"):
    your_function()
```

Comment: so I should set the host to env.host_string?

Comment: @DavidTzoor I'm not sure what you mean by global variables. If you mean `with settings(host_string=MYHOST)` where `MYHOST` is a python global, yes. Otherwise, you should probably ask another question

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on why this has worked for me?

Comment: @DavidTzoor you mean the mechanism? `settings` is a context manager that manipulates `env`. [Here's the relevant documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.settings)